# How to remove Comma and '[]' around the string in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am trying to re-create a string set of values in an element as a seperated node sets for each.

The XML example:

```
<VALUES>
   <VALUE>[example],[example1],[good,example],[test]</VALUE>
<VALUES>
```

XSLT :

```
    <xsl:template name="SimpleStringLoop">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($input) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="v" select="substring-before($input, ',')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$v"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, ',')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VALUE">
    <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'['),']')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output:

```
<VALUES>
   <VALUE>example</VALUE>
   <VALUE>example1</VALUE>
   <VALUE>good,example</VALUE>
   <VALUE>test</VALUE>
<VALUES>
```

I was able to split by the comma. I think also for-each value by counting the commas and creating the same amount of element and writing them makes sense. How to get rid of "[]" around the strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `analyze-string`, in XSLT 3 you can call it as an XPath function and simply process the XML `fn:match` elements the function returns:

```
  <xsl:template match="VALUE">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '\[([^\[]+)\]')//fn:match"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

full example

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="VALUE">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '\[([^\[]+)\]')//fn:match"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fn:match">
      <VALUE>{fn:group[@nr = 1]}</VALUE>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2 you can use `xsl:analyze-string` instead and then use `xsl:matching-substring` inside to output a `VALUE` element:

```
  <xsl:template match="VALUE">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[([^\[]+)\]">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <VALUE>
                  <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
              </VALUE>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/pNEhB3b

Comment: Thanks Martin!  I needed the XSLT 2.0 solution. Working very well as always